# Tag excerpts on profiles don't wrap

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-excerpt

Currently the tag excerpts on profiles refuse to wrap due to a rule inherited from the parent elements:

[image]

This is the rule in question:

```css
.ws-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

And this is how the DOM looks like:

```html
<div class="flex--item ws-nowrap">
  <a href="/search?q=..." class="s-tag js-hoverable-post-tag js-gps-track" rel="tag">...</a>
  <div style="/* ... */" class="esc-remove magic-popup">...</div>
  <a href="/help/badges/..." class="badge-tag bg-transparent bc-transparent m0">...</a>
</div>
```

This is (presumably) irrelevant to *[Update: New Colors Launched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394232)*, so I'm posting here instead.

Comment: [I can reproduce it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vK7om.png) on FF 117. I went to [OP's profile page on main](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21305238/insync?tab=profile) and hovered over the tags in the "Top tags" section. Same thing happens [in other profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTRkk.png). [Same thing happens on Meta.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erQot.png) However, the bug doesn't show up in the [tags section in the profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21305238/insync?tab=tags): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVqCq.png)

Comment: Sweet, `!important`, now the child element is gonna have to have that as well xD

Comment: Also on MSE: [Text is not wrapping in the tag popup of "Top Tags" section in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/394423)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, see [my answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/394423/text-is-not-wrapping-in-the-tag-popup-of-top-tags-section-in-profile/394481#394481). Thanks for the report (and the debugging)!

(And you're right, it was unrelated to the color update.)